# How to see a specific map in hazelcast console?

Tags: caching, hazelcast

Hazelcast has a default map named m when we use it from console.
We can do - m.put , m.get etc. But suppose I want to create a named map or I want to view a map already created by some application. Is it possible in hazelcast console ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the command
ns [the_map_name]
//switch the namespace for using the distributed queue/map/set/list  (defaults to "default")

m is not the name of map, it is part of the command.

For example you have a map named "students" and want to put a new record to this map.
You should:

```
> ns students  
> m.put(key, value)
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't knew about Namespaces.